# Docker build push pull should be possible without sudo

Tags: docker

Why do I need sudo for building a Docker image and push it, or why isnt there a socket for unpriviledged commands? I mean this makes no sense. Running containers has to be secured of course, but build or push or pull should be no security issue.

Thanks

Comment: Building basically involves running.

Answer (score 1):

Add your user to the `docker` group for unprivileged Docker command execution, this is covered in the post-installation docs
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

However as mentioned in the security docs, allowing someone to control docker is nearly equivalent to giving them root permissions: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface